# dotnetopenauth.messaging.httprequestinfo' does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, dotnetopenauth, http-request

I use asp.net mvc3  with razor code.I'm trying this authcontroller.

```
 HttpRequestInfo clientResponseInfo = new HttpRequestInfo("GET", auth,  headers, null);
```

I get a redline below HttpRequestInfo says "dotnetopenauth.messaging.httprequestinfo' does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments "